# SpannableStringBuilder append a SpannableString object not show the span?

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, spannable

I am trying to use the SpannableStringBuilder to implement spannable color to all occurrence of a given character sequence in the sentence, just like:

```
val spannableStr1 = SpannableString("hello world!")
spannableStr1.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")),
        0, 3, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
val spannableBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder()
spannableBuilder.append(spannableStr1)
spannableBuilder.append(spannableStr1)
tvDemo.text = spannableBuilder
```

and this resulted to:

[image]

I need the second occurrence of the characters `hel` also in red color. So I tried to append spannableStr1  again, but it seems not working.

Is there any way to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

The span on spannableStr1 is set for 0-3.  Unfortunately once you add it to the spannable string builder the second time, it's still 0-3.  This causes the problem here-  you colored the same part red twice.

A better way of doing this is not to add spans to the text.  Instead, just append the text and add the spans directly to the SpannableStringBuilder.  This means the first span should be (0,3) and the second one should be (index of second h, index of second h + 3)

```
val spannableStr1 ="hello world!"
val spannableBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder()
spannableBuilder.append(spannableStr1)
spannableBuilder.append(spannableStr1)
spannableBuilder.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")),
        0, 3, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
spannableBuilder.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")),
        spannableStr1.length, spannableStr1.length + 3, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
tvDemo.text = spannableBuilder
```

Comment: I try to use anthor SpannableString object named spannableStr2(val spannableStr2 ="hello world!"), and set the ForegroundColorSpan from 5 to 7, and append to the spannableBuilder, it still colored the [0, 3] part.